# The desired orientation (1) isn't supported by the currently integrated Nextpeer's resource bundle

Tags: ios, cocoa, nextpeer

I'm using `Nextpeer` in `Cocos` for multi-player game, and want to set portrait orientation for `NextpeerSettingInitialDashboardOrientation`. I'm using this code for that :

```
 NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], NextpeerSettingSupportsDashboardRotation,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:NPNotificationPosition_BOTTOM], NextpeerSettingNotificationPosition,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], NextpeerSettingInitialDashboardOrientation,
                              nil];

[Nextpeer initializeWithProductKey:@"ID" andSettings:settings andDelegates:
 [NPDelegatesContainer containerWithNextpeerDelegate:self notificationDelegate:nil tournamentDelegate:self currencyDelegate:nil]];
```

But i'm getting this **warning**, and my orientation is not set to `portrait`. It's set it to `Landscape`. My default orientation is `portrait`.

```
Nextpeer warning: The desired orientation (1) isn't supported by the currently integrated Nextpeer's resource bundle.
```

- How to change *NextpeerSettingSupportsDashboardRotation* ?
- How to resolve this warning ?

Answer (score 0):

[Nextpeer](http://nextpeer.com) has different resource bundles based on your project orientation and universal support.
You need to make sure that you integrate the correspondent resource bundle. For example if your is landscape universal then you need to set the `NPResources_iPad_iPhone_Landscape` bundle in your project as instructed in the iOS integration guide.

In order to change the `NextpeerSettingSupportsDashboardRotation` value to TRUE just change the object value like this:

```
 NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE], NextpeerSettingSupportsDashboardRotation,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:NPNotificationPosition_BOTTOM], NextpeerSettingNotificationPosition,
                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], NextpeerSettingInitialDashboardOrientation,
                          nil];
```